# Gitlab Registries and Packages

Tags: gitlab

My question is very simple. I found a lot of examples and tutorials on how to use the registry in GitLab.I need this for my angular libraries, but why I can't show the Registry button. Gitlab is hosted on my server.[[image: Gitlab MenuServer]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume what you need is npm registry, that you need version at least 11.7

in the project, go to settings -> general -> visibility, project features, permissions

under 'Repository', you will see the last item 'package', enable it and save change, you will see the packages registry then

if you want to use docker container registry, you may try edit the gitlab.rb and find gitlab_rails['registry_enabled'], set it to 'true' and reconfigure. Hope this helps.